# Python / Django - Form Selection Value is Object Id... Can't Get Object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form select box that has values corresponding to objects.  The user selects an input and the form submits.  I then want to take that value and retrieve the object that has an ID equivalent to the selected form value.  However, when I try to do so, I'm getting an error like so:

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cars'

Example:

```
if form.is_valid():
    car = Car.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['id'])
```

I'm guessing the problem is that the returned value is a string and NOT an integer.  In PHP this is SIMPLE.  How do I typecast or use the returned form value to get an associated object?

Seems as though Django is not returning the value of the form element, but instead the user visible option name...

Form Class:

```
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

Html Form:

```
<form action="">
  <select name="id">
      {% for car in cars %}
          <option value="{{car.id}}">{{car.title}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a clean solution to this? I think I am having the same problem but could only find a shady solution which I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` field has to be an integer, or a string that can be converted to an integer.
Simple as that!

Somehow, your `form.cleaned_data['id']` is returning a model called `Cars`

Ensure it returns a number if you want to pass it into `get(id=`

Comment: Ahhh.  After printing the value to my console, I can see that the text of the select field is coming through as the value...  So, form.cleaned_data['id'] would be the NAME in the following example: <select value="2">NAME</select> .  How can I get the value?

Comment: Can I please see your template and form code? PS: values are put on `<option>` tags, not `<select>`

Comment: Haha. Ooops. template: <select name="id"> {% for car in cars %} <option value="{{car.id}}">{{car.title}}</option> {% endfor %} </select> form: class CarForm(forms.ModelForm): TYPES = [['radio1','Choice1'],['radio2','Choice2']] link_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES, required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'related-resource-type'})) class Meta: model = Car The form elements are in html and added to within the form tags... Perhaps that is the problem? These form elements HAVE to be defined within the form class???

Comment: No dude, that's insane! `<select>` doesn't even post the text values. It only posts the selected `value="2"` part.  Can you update your post (instead of comment) with your entire form and view? To me, that original error sounds like something else

Comment: I added it.  The only thing I can think of is that I created the select box independent of django forms...  But you're right.  This shouldn't EVER give me anything other than the value selected?.?.?.  Also, this form has been simplified from the whole form i am using for my client.

Comment: We need to see the whole form.. if cleaned_data is returning something funky, we should see the clean() methods and the clean_field methods.. That's what I got my money on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelChoiceField instead of generating the select using HTML

in forms.py:

```
class CarSelectForm(forms.Form):
    car = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

in view.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    car = form.cleaned_data['car']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bad, but I think working answer. If anyone has a real solution, please post because I still need it.

(I'm using a modelformset, but just a modelform may work the same)

For me, the {{ form.id }} works on the page (puts the id) and comes back correctly in the POST data. However, somewhere along the line it gets converted (as Yuji said in his post) into the model object represented by that id and that is what is in cleaned_data.

In short, change

```
car = Car.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['id'])
```

to

```
car = form.cleaned_data['id']
```

I think it just looks like a string just because when you print or debug, it's using your str or unicode representation.

Repeat: This is almost certainly a side effect or bad way to do things. If I figure out a better way, I'll post it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue... so I tried the following:

```
ts_1 = form.cleaned_data['lista_trabajos']
ts_2 = request.POST['lista_trabajos']
print(ts_1) # this returns what user sees, ex: 1 - folders
print(ts_2) # this returns value from that option, in my case: 1
```

Unfortunately, I have been reading that by using raw POST data is not recommended. At the moment, I cannot figure out how to validate and get the raw POST data by using something similar to "clean_data".

You can read about this in: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=8sU7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=form+cleaned_data+to+get+raw+post+data&source=bl&ots=RN9WKRaGJs&sig=QpSoPdI9YSHSNk0zAQIO8phSbOw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBouHattnaAhULFZAKHUKmA4QQ6AEIRzAD#v=onepage&q=form%20cleaned_data%20to%20get%20raw%20post%20data&f=false